# Is there a fully pre-assembled computer of Raspberry Pi, which I could just buy and start using, without having to put it together ?

Tags: purchasing

Most buying options of Raspberry Pi talk about a "complete kit", which I guess, the buyer has to put together or assemble based on a guide. (Yeah, I understand the excitement of doing it). But is there a pre-built all-assembling-done-already type of commercial computer, to which we could just attach monitor, usb hub, mouse etc and start using right away, without having to "follow a manual" and assemble it on arrival ?

Is it like there is no business case for it, because most adopters of Raspberry Pi have the technical curiosity or knowledge to assemble it ?

If it helps in context, I am looking to buy such a one (right now as a fantasy, but later I may put it some use), in India, online.

Comment: The only RPi that requires actual "assembly" is the Zero. If (and only if) you want to use the GPIO pins, you have to solder them on. The 3B comes pre-assembled, and as others have noted, you pretty much snap it into a case. It takes less time than the most basic plastic model sold for kids. Don't let the word "kit" scare you off, they're a breeze to put together. The big advantage to the kit is that you are guaranteed to have everything you need for "day 1" in the box, without potential frustration of realizing you're missing a key part. You will want a display and keyboard.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

There is nothing to "putting a kit together" its just a board pushed into a case, no screws nothing. There is no "real" assembly. In fact you dont even need a case, just plug in power, keyboard, mouse and a screen, or none and connect via ssh. A quick youtube video search and you will understand how simple it is.

Answer (score 4):

A starter kit is very basic. It has case, power supply, NOOBS Sd card, maybe cables and heat sinks. Takes a total of 1 - 5 min to put it together. Here is a picture of a kit.
[image: picture of kit]

Comment: The CanaKit boxes are nice, and contain a quality power supply, which is key to a good RPi experience. Quality of the power adapter and the microSD card are key. Adafruit also sells quality components. Beware the cheaper kits with questionable contents.

Answer (score 1):

The reason none of these products are available pre-assembled is because that requires FCC certification which is very cost-prohibitive for these small companies. Even though the RPi itself is FCC certified, it is only certified by itself, i.e. without any enclosure. As soon as you add an enclosure, this changes possible (even unintentional) radiation characteristics and therefore requires re-certification, which nobody wants to do. The only workaround to this is if the original device itself (the RPi) was classified as a modular component (which is what makes selling pre-assembled PCs legal), but unfortunately this is not the case.

See this article for more information: https://www.sparkfun.com/tutorials/398

Comment: While this is true as far as it goes, the RPi *is* nowadays available pre-assembled.  The RPi-400.